# How to access images from stereo camera?

Tags: android, camera, stereo-3d

I am trying to figure out how to access images from both rear cameras (stereo cameras) in Android 7 running on the [Open-Q™ 835 HDK Development Kit](https://www.intrinsyc.com/snapdragon-embedded-development-kits/open-q-835-development-kit/) with [Open-Q™ 835 Camera](https://shop.intrinsyc.com/collections/dragonboard-accessories/products/open-q-835-camera) camera module.

Currently, I see only one rear and one front camera using the following code:

```
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

    int selected = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);

        if( info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK ) {
            selected = i;
            //break;
        } else {
            // default to a front facing camera if a back facing one can't be found
            selected = i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might want to ask here: https://faq.intrinsyc.com/ Although given that the board firmware may be coming from Qualcomm access to detailed material may be through a partner/ODM portal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I posted a question on intrinsyc site as well however it seems not to be very active.